# Unable to start an instance of sshd server

Tags: ssh, sshd

I tried to start an instance of my own (i am not root) sshd server on a remote machine , but it fails:

```
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_4.3p2
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: private host key: #0 type 1 RSA
debug1: setgroups() failed: Operation not permitted
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-f'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='sshd_config'
debug1: rexec_argv[4]='-h'
debug1: rexec_argv[5]='ssh_host_rsa_key'
debug1: rexec_argv[6]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[7]='55000'
debug1: Bind to port 55000 on ::.
debug1: Bind to port 55000 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 55000 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.
Cannot bind any address.
```

Part of my sshd_config file:

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.73 2005/12/06 22:38:28 reyk Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

 # The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
 # possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
 # default value.

 Port 55000
 #Protocol 2,1
 Protocol 2
 #AddressFamily any
 #ListenAddress
 #ListenAddress ::
```

If i uncomment listener address and use any ip, obviously my own ip (172.16.13.126) it gives the following error:

```
Bind to port 55000 on 172.16.13.126 failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Cannot bind any address.
```

Comment: what's the result of `sudo netstat -np | grep :55000`?

Comment: i am not root user

Comment: How about `netstat -n | grep :55000`?  If you see a listener, try running `sshd` on a different port.

Answer (score 1):

> `Bind to port 55000 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Address already in use.`

Hey,

as the second to last line of your sshd output describes, the port 55000 seems to be taken by another process. You may try to configure another port in your `sshd_config` file.
This reply here also gives a good explanation of how to run sshd as unprivileged user:

[Thread: How do I run sshd as a particular user?](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2008-04/msg00363.html)

I haven't tried it, but the descriptions seems reasonable at first sight.